# VS Code debug C++, the args increase there words

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

When I debug the .cpp code, the actual args number is increase three(the debugger output photo) more than I input(the launch.json photo), I really confused with it, I will appreciate your help!

the debugger output
[image: the debugger output]

launch.json
[image: launch.json]

Comment: They look like file redirections. inside your c program print the elements of the `argv` array

Comment: It's just the debuggers way of telling you that the standard input `<`, standard output `1>`, and standard error `2>` streams are attached to the console. They're not really command line arguments at all, and won't be present in your `argv` array.

Comment: First, Thanks to your reply! 
I printf the `argc` and the content of `argv`,but both of them actually in my `argv` array.
this is the output:
`the argc:7
D:\codes\encry\build\1caesar.exe -e D:\codes\encry\input\plain.txt 3 2>CON 1>CON <CON`